# How to convert HttpRequestBase to HttpRequestMessage, considering header names?

Tags: asp.net, httpclient

I am wrapping an `HttpRequestBase` as an `HttpRequestMessage`, which requires all the headers be copied over. But since `HttpRequestMessage` is particular about which headers apply to the request object vs. the Content object, the `httpRequest.Headers.Add` line below sometimes throws InvalidOperationException.

```
public static HttpRequestMessage AsHttpRequestMessage(this HttpRequestBase request) {
    Requires.NotNull(request, "request");

    var httpRequest = new HttpRequestMessage(new HttpMethod(request.HttpMethod), request.Url);
    foreach (string header in request.Headers) {
        httpRequest.Headers.Add(header, request.Headers.GetValues(header));
    }

    if (request.Form != null) {
        // Avoid a request message that will try to read the request stream twice for already parsed data.
        httpRequest.Content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(request.Form.AsKeyValuePairs());
    } else if (request.InputStream != null) {
        httpRequest.Content = new StreamContent(request.InputStream);
    }

    return httpRequest;
}
```

Obviously I'd like my code to not throw exceptions, but rather appropriately apply each header to the appropriate object. How can I predict this? Is there any method I can use to test the applicability of a header short of one that generates and catches exceptions?

Comment: I'm actually finding out it's harder than even just header placement. Some headers (like Content-Type) can't be `Add`ed at all, but can only be set using the ContentType property. `Accept` is another header that apparently I must parse and pass in using richer objects. Surely this work has already been done and I don't have to redo it here?

Comment: In your code i saw that you either read request.Form or request.Content . I am curious to know if a HttpRequestBase object could have both having important content

Comment: @StackOverflowVeryHelpful: No. Form data comes in the Content. So if Form is not null, it means the request carried an HTTP header indicating that the request input stream carried form data and ASP.NET parsed it for us, in which case there's nothing left of the InputStream.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It turns out it's quite simple. This snippet comes heavily inspired from [ASP.NET's own open sourced source code](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/4764b0111b91#src/System.Web.Http.WebHost/HttpControllerHandler.cs).

```
/// <summary>
/// Clones an <see cref="HttpWebRequest" /> in order to send it again.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="message">The message to set headers on.</param>
/// <param name="request">The request with headers to clone.</param>
internal static void CopyHeadersFrom(this HttpRequestMessage message, HttpRequestBase request) {
    Requires.NotNull(request, "request");
    Requires.NotNull(message, "message");

    foreach (string headerName in request.Headers) {
        string[] headerValues = request.Headers.GetValues(headerName);
        if (!message.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(headerName, headerValues)) {
            message.Content.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation(headerName, headerValues);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use TryAddWithoutValidation instead of Add to avoid the throwing. You need to be careful about whether to call GetBufferlessStream or not depending on whether you want to buffer the request. See ConvertRequest method in the following class: http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/4764b0111b91#src/System.Web.Http.WebHost/HttpControllerHandler.cs